# Grapevine sample REST server code returns a "Not found" response

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

I'd like to implement a simple REST server using [Grapevine Plus](https://github.com/scottoffen/GrapevinePlus) and am following the examples provided on the [wiki](https://github.com/scottoffen/Grapevine/wiki/Getting-Started-RestServer). I installed Grapevine Plus 3.0.4 via NuGet. I'm running the following code, but when I navigate to http://localhost:1234 via browser, or if I send a GET request via REST client browser plugin, all I get is a **"Not found"** response:

```
// Program.cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var server = new RESTServer();
    server.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to Continue...");
    Console.ReadLine();
    server.Stop();
}

// TestResource.cs
public sealed class TestResource : RESTResource
{
    [RESTRoute]
    public void HandleAllGetRequests(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        this.SendTextResponse(context, "GET is a success!");
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What is the name of the console project you created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the code you've written looks fine (and still runs fine for me), I think you might be running up against [this project naming issue in Grapevine 3.0.x](https://github.com/scottoffen/Grapevine/issues/25).

This is no longer an issue in version 3.1.0, but for the older 3.0.x versions you need to make sure you don't include the word '**grapevine**' in your assembly name.